# Windows Service Development Win32API C++ (g++ and Visual C++)

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, windows-services, g++

I created a sample service using Win32 API and C++.
I have once used Mingw g++ (7.1 - C++14) and Visual Studio 2010 independently.

The service I created using g++ does not start (after installation) and gives Error 1053: "The service did not respond in a timely fashion" when attempting to start, stop or pause a service.

I created an service using Visual C++ 2010 (same code with minor modification - for Unicode support)  and it run properly on development machine (after installation).
However when I run the same service (after installation) I get error Error 1053: "The service did not respond in a timely fashion" when attempting to start, stop or pause a service .

Reference Article : [Simple Windows Service in C++](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/499465/Simple-Windows-Service-in-Cplusplus)

### Visual C++ :

WindowsService.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "Common.hpp"

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
*/

SERVICE_STATUS          serviceStatus       = {0};
SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE   serviceStatusHandle = NULL;
HANDLE                  serviceStopEvent    = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

VOID    WINAPI ServiceMain (DWORD, LPSTR *);
VOID    WINAPI ServiceCtrlHandler(DWORD);
DWORD   WINAPI ServiceWorkerThread(LPVOID);

#define SERVICE_NAME                       _T("My Sample Service")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY serviceTable[] =
    {
        {SERVICE_NAME, (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)ServiceMain},
        {NULL, NULL}
    };

if(StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(serviceTable) == FALSE)
{
    DWORD errorMessageID = ::GetLastError();
    FileOperations fo;
    fo.printError(fo.getLastErrorAsString(errorMessageID));
    return errorMessageID;
}
//cout << "Hello World";
FileOperations fo;
fo.printError("Testing Error");
fo.printLog("Ishaan Says Hello World");
    return 0;
}

VOID WINAPI ServiceMain(DWORD argc, LPSTR *argv)
{
    DWORD status = E_FAIL;
    serviceStatusHandle = RegisterServiceCtrlHandler(SERVICE_NAME, ServiceCtrlHandler);
    if(serviceStatusHandle == NULL)
    {
        FileOperations fo;
        fo.printError(fo.getLastErrorAsString(::GetLastError()));
        return;
    }

    //Tell The Service Controller we are starting
    ZeroMemory(&serviceStatus, sizeof(serviceStatus));
    serviceStatus.dwServiceType             = SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS;
    serviceStatus.dwControlsAccepted        = 0;
    serviceStatus.dwCurrentState            = SERVICE_START_PENDING;
    serviceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode           = 0;
    serviceStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
    serviceStatus.dwCheckPoint              = 0;

    if(SetServiceStatus(serviceStatusHandle, &serviceStatus) ==  FALSE)
    {
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service : Service Main : SetSeviceStatus returned error. First (1) If"));
        FileOperations fo;
        fo.printError("My Sample Service : Service Main : SetSeviceStatus returned error");
}

//Preform task necessary to start a service here

//Create a stop event to wait on later

    serviceStopEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

    if(serviceStopEvent == NULL)
    {
        serviceStatus.dwControlsAccepted    = 0;
        serviceStatus.dwCurrentState        = SERVICE_STOP;
        serviceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode       = GetLastError();
        serviceStatus.dwCheckPoint          = 1;

        if(SetServiceStatus(serviceStatusHandle, &serviceStatus) == FALSE)
        {
            OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service : ServiceMain : SetServiceStatus returned error. Second (2) If"));
            FileOperations fo;
            fo.printError("My Sample Service : ServiceMain : SetServiceStatus returned error. Second (2) If");
        }
        return;
    }

    //Tell Service Controller we are started
    serviceStatus.dwControlsAccepted    = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP;
    serviceStatus.dwCurrentState        = SERVICE_RUNNING;
    serviceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode       = 0;
    serviceStatus.dwCheckPoint          = 0;

    if(SetServiceStatus(serviceStatusHandle, &serviceStatus) == FALSE)
    {
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service : ServiceMain : SetServiceStatus returned error. Tell Service Controller we are started"));
        FileOperations fo;
        fo.printError("My Sample Service : ServiceMain : SetServiceStatus returned error. Tell Service Controller we are started");
    }

    // Start a thread that will perform the main task of the service
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ServiceWorkerThread, NULL, 0, NULL);

   // Wait until our worker thread exits signaling that the service needs to stop
   WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

   //Perform Clean Up
   CloseHandle(serviceStopEvent);

   serviceStatus.dwControlsAccepted    = 0;
   serviceStatus.dwCurrentState        = SERVICE_STOPPED;
   serviceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode       = 0;
   serviceStatus.dwCheckPoint          = 3;

   if(SetServiceStatus(serviceStatusHandle, &serviceStatus) ==  FALSE)
   {
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service : Service Main : SetSeviceStatus returned error during exiting"));
        FileOperations fo;
        fo.printError("My Sample Service : Service Main : SetSeviceStatus returned error during exiting");
    }

    return;
}

VOID WINAPI ServiceCtrlHandler(DWORD ctrlCode)
{
    switch(ctrlCode)
    {
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP :
        if(serviceStatus.dwCurrentState != SERVICE_RUNNING)
            break;

        serviceStatus.dwControlsAccepted    = 0;
        serviceStatus.dwCurrentState        = SERVICE_STOP_PENDING;
        serviceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode       = 0;
        serviceStatus.dwCheckPoint          = 4;

        if(SetServiceStatus(serviceStatusHandle, &serviceStatus) ==  FALSE)
        {
            OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceCtrlHandler: SetServiceStatus returned error"));
            FileOperations fo;
            fo.printError("My Sample Service: ServiceCtrlHandler: SetServiceStatus returned error");
        }

        SetEvent(serviceStopEvent);
        break;

    default :
        break;
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI ServiceWorkerThread(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    while(WaitForSingleObject(serviceStopEvent, 0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {

        FileOperations fo;
        fo.printLog("Inside Service Thread");
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

Common.hpp

```
#ifndef COMMON_COMMON_HPP_
#define COMMON_COMMON_HPP_

#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

#define RETURN_SUCCESS  true
#define RETURN_FAILURE  false

class FileOperations
{
public :
    void    printError(string);
    void    printLog(string);
    string  getLastErrorAsString(DWORD);
private :
    void getDateTime(void);
    string DateTime;
};
```

---

stdafx.h

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <cerrno>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
```

---

Common.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Common.hpp"

using namespace std;

bool GlobalVariables::startCapture = false;


void FileOperations::printLog(string str)
{
    ofstream of;
    of.open("C:\Log.dat", ios::out | ios::app);
    this->getDateTime();
    of << "[" << DateTime << "]" << "\t\t" << str << endl;
    of.close();
}

void FileOperations::printError(string str)
{
    ofstream of;
    of.open("C:\Error.dat", ios::out | ios::app);
    this->getDateTime();
    of << "[" << DateTime << "]" << "\t\t" << str << endl;
    of.close();
}

void FileOperations::getDateTime(void)
{
    time_t  now;
    tm      *dtStruct;

    now = time(0);
    dtStruct = localtime(&now);

    DateTime.clear();

    DateTime = to_string((long long)dtStruct->tm_mday) + ":" + to_string((long long)1 + dtStruct->tm_mon) + ":" + to_string((long long)1900 + dtStruct->tm_year) + "\t" +
        to_string((long long)1 + dtStruct->tm_hour) + ":" + to_string((long long)1 + dtStruct->tm_min) + ":" + to_string((long long)1 + dtStruct->tm_sec);

}

//Returns the last Win32 error, in string format. Returns an empty string if there is no error.
string FileOperations::getLastErrorAsString(DWORD errorMessageID)
{
    if(errorMessageID == 0)
        return string("No error message has been recorded"); //No error message has been recorded

    LPSTR messageBuffer = nullptr;
    size_t size = FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                                 NULL, errorMessageID, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPWSTR)&messageBuffer, 0, NULL);

    string message(messageBuffer, size);

    //Free the buffer.
    LocalFree(messageBuffer);

    return message;
}
```

---

## g++ :

main.cpp

```
#include "Common.hpp"

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */

SERVICE_STATUS          serviceStatus       = {0};
SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE   serviceStatusHandle = NULL;
HANDLE                  serviceStopEvent    = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

VOID    WINAPI ServiceMain (DWORD, LPSTR *);
VOID    WINAPI ServiceCtrlHandler(DWORD);
DWORD   WINAPI ServiceWorkerThread(LPVOID);

#define SERVICE_NAME                       "My Sample Service"

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY serviceTable[] =
    {
        {SERVICE_NAME, (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)ServiceMain},
        {NULL, NULL}
    };

    if(StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(serviceTable) == FALSE)
    {
        DWORD errorMessageID = ::GetLastError();
        FileOperations fo;
        fo.printError(fo.getLastErrorAsString(errorMessageID));
        return errorMessageID;
    }
    //cout << "Hello World";
    FileOperations fo;
    fo.printError("Testing Error");
    fo.printLog("Ishaan Says Hello World");
    return 0;
}

VOID WINAPI ServiceMain(DWORD argc, LPSTR *argv)
{
    DWORD status = E_FAIL;
    serviceStatusHandle = RegisterServiceCtrlHandler(SERVICE_NAME, ServiceCtrlHandler);
    if(serviceStatusHandle == NULL)
    {
        FileOperations fo;
        fo.printError(fo.getLastErrorAsString(::GetLastError()));
        return;
    }

    //Tell The Service Controller we are starting
    ZeroMemory(&serviceStatus, sizeof(serviceStatus));
    serviceStatus.dwServiceType             = SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS;
    serviceStatus.dwControlsAccepted        = 0;
    serviceStatus.dwCurrentState            = SERVICE_START_PENDING;
    serviceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode           = 0;
    serviceStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
    serviceStatus.dwCheckPoint              = 0;

    if(SetServiceStatus(serviceStatusHandle, &serviceStatus) ==  FALSE)
    {
        OutputDebugString("My Sample Service : Service Main : SetSeviceStatus returned error. First (1) If");
        FileOperations fo;
        fo.printError("My Sample Service : Service Main : SetSeviceStatus returned error");
    }

    //Preform task necessary to start a service here

    //Create a stop event to wait on later

    serviceStopEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

    if(serviceStopEvent == NULL)
    {
        serviceStatus.dwControlsAccepted    = 0;
        serviceStatus.dwCurrentState        = SERVICE_STOP;
        serviceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode       = GetLastError();
        serviceStatus.dwCheckPoint          = 1;

        if(SetServiceStatus(serviceStatusHandle, &serviceStatus) == FALSE)
        {
            OutputDebugString("My Sample Service : ServiceMain : SetServiceStatus returned error. Second (2) If");
            FileOperations fo;
            fo.printError("My Sample Service : ServiceMain : SetServiceStatus returned error. Second (2) If");
        }
        return;
    }

    //Tell Service Controller we are started
    serviceStatus.dwControlsAccepted    = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP;
    serviceStatus.dwCurrentState        = SERVICE_RUNNING;
    serviceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode       = 0;
    serviceStatus.dwCheckPoint          = 0;

    if(SetServiceStatus(serviceStatusHandle, &serviceStatus) == FALSE)
    {
        OutputDebugString("My Sample Service : ServiceMain : SetServiceStatus returned error. Tell Service Controller we are started");
        FileOperations fo;
        fo.printError("My Sample Service : ServiceMain : SetServiceStatus returned error. Tell Service Controller we are started");
    }

    // Start a thread that will perform the main task of the service
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ServiceWorkerThread, NULL, 0, NULL);

    // Wait until our worker thread exits signaling that the service needs to stop
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

    //Perform Clean Up
    CloseHandle(serviceStopEvent);

    serviceStatus.dwControlsAccepted    = 0;
    serviceStatus.dwCurrentState        = SERVICE_STOPPED;
    serviceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode       = 0;
    serviceStatus.dwCheckPoint          = 3;

    if(SetServiceStatus(serviceStatusHandle, &serviceStatus) ==  FALSE)
    {
        OutputDebugString("My Sample Service : Service Main : SetSeviceStatus returned error during exiting");
        FileOperations fo;
        fo.printError("My Sample Service : Service Main : SetSeviceStatus returned error during exiting");
    }

    return;
}

VOID WINAPI ServiceCtrlHandler(DWORD ctrlCode)
{
    switch(ctrlCode)
    {
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP :
        if(serviceStatus.dwCurrentState != SERVICE_RUNNING)
            break;

        serviceStatus.dwControlsAccepted    = 0;
        serviceStatus.dwCurrentState        = SERVICE_STOP_PENDING;
        serviceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode       = 0;
        serviceStatus.dwCheckPoint          = 4;

        if(SetServiceStatus(serviceStatusHandle, &serviceStatus) ==  FALSE)
        {
            OutputDebugString("My Sample Service: ServiceCtrlHandler: SetServiceStatus returned error");
            FileOperations fo;
            fo.printError("My Sample Service: ServiceCtrlHandler: SetServiceStatus returned error");
        }

        SetEvent(serviceStopEvent);
        break;

    default :
        break;
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI ServiceWorkerThread(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    while(WaitForSingleObject(serviceStopEvent, 0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {
        FileOperations fo;
        fo.printLog("Inside Service Thread");
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

---

Common.cpp

```
#include "Common.hpp"

using namespace std;

bool GlobalVariables::startCapture = false;


void FileOperations::printLog(string str)
{
    ofstream of;
    of.open("Log.dat", ios::out | ios::app);
    this->getDateTime();
    of << "[" << DateTime << "]" << "\t\t" << str << endl;
    of.close();
}

void FileOperations::printError(string str)
{
    ofstream of;
    of.open("Error.dat", ios::out | ios::app);
    this->getDateTime();
    of << "[" << DateTime << "]" << "\t\t" << str << endl;
    of.close();
}

void FileOperations::getDateTime(void)
{
    time_t  now;
    tm      *dtStruct;

    now = time(0);
    dtStruct = localtime(&now);

    DateTime.clear();

    DateTime = to_string(dtStruct->tm_mday) + ":" + to_string(1 + dtStruct->tm_mon) + ":" + to_string(1900 + dtStruct->tm_year) + "\t" +
        to_string(1 + dtStruct->tm_hour) + ":" + to_string(1 + dtStruct->tm_min) + ":" + to_string(1 + dtStruct->tm_sec);

}

//Returns the last Win32 error, in string format. Returns an empty string if there is no error.
string FileOperations::getLastErrorAsString(DWORD errorMessageID)
{
    if(errorMessageID == 0)
        return string("No error message has been recorded"); //No error message has been recorded

    LPSTR messageBuffer = nullptr;
    size_t size = FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                                 NULL, errorMessageID, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPSTR)&messageBuffer, 0, NULL);

    string message(messageBuffer, size);

    //Free the buffer.
    LocalFree(messageBuffer);

    return message;
}
```

---

Common.hpp

```
#ifndef COMMON_COMMON_HPP_
#define COMMON_COMMON_HPP_

using namespace std;

#include <ctime>
#include <cerrno>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <thread>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdbool>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
//#include <pthread.h>


//#include "CommandList.hpp"

#define RETURN_SUCCESS  true
#define RETURN_FAILURE  false

class FileOperations
{
public :
    void    printError(string);
    void    printLog(string);
    string  getLastErrorAsString(DWORD);
private :
    void getDateTime(void);
    string DateTime;
};

class GlobalVariables
{
public :
    static bool startCapture;
};



#endif /* COMMON_COMMON_HPP_ */
```

I used administrative account to install and run the service.

Comment: Have you installed appropriate dll dependencies?

Comment: Sir, can you enlighten me which dlls would be required. The article does not mention any such dependencies. The service did run on Visual Studio 2010 development machine but failed on target machine. The service failed when using g++ even on development machine.

Comment: For VS you need to install Visual Studio 2010 c++ redistributable package that can be downloaded from MS website. For gcc you probably need to use libstdc++ dll that comes with gcc and exception handling dll. You can check the list of dll dependencies of your executable using tools such Dependency Walker.

Comment: Both these dependencies are met. As these are standard dependencies I had copied libstdc++.dll in my executable folder (in case of g++). I have also installed redistributes from 2005 to 2017. I have even built the files with static flag enabled but I still get the same error.

Comment: *"same code with minor modification - for Unicode support"* - There is no Unicode support in your Visual C++ code. You have decidedly disabled it (considering your `ServiceMain` signature). If you haven't, then your `(LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)ServiceMain` cast is doing you a disservice, by silencing the compiler that's trying to inform you about your bug. The code should compile without a cast. If it doesn't, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Check event viewer and see if any error message is present for the service.

Comment: will be more easy say where error, if you paste binary exe as is for debug.

Comment: @rbMm, Sir I couldn't get you? Do you want me to upload my executables?

Comment: @DarkSorrow - yes, if have your exe much more easy say why he fail

Comment: Visual C++ Executable : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6838dRw0kEnR1o2R2JGTnBtams/view?usp=sharing

Comment: G++ Executable : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6838dRw0kEnYk9TUVVoM1ZzMGc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: in case g++ you program fail because **libstdc++-6.dll** and **libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll** missing. in case c++ fail because **MSVCR100D.dll** and **MSVCP100D.dll** is missing

Comment: @RbMm, Adding libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll in my service's executable folder solved the problem. Thank You for the solution. Can you educate me how identifiy necessary dependencies by analyzing the executables.

Comment: but this is very simply. exist many different gui pe viewers which show iports. possible also use `link.exe` for this run "link.exe /dump /imports some.exe > log.txt"

Comment: @RbMm, Thanks for your help. Using NikPEViewer from http://www.codedebug.com/php/Products/Products_NikPEViewer_12v.php